# Kubernetes - how to list conditions that are not met

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I upgraded k8s version on GCP to 1.21.6-gke.1500. Some of my pods are stuck in the status "ContainerCreating". When I describe them, I see these errors:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------       ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    12m                    default-scheduler  Successfully assigned gamma/xxxx-d58747f46-j7fzs to gke-us-east4-gke-us-east4-xxxx--6c23c312-p5q2
  Warning  FailedMount  10m                    kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[nfs-data], unattached volumes=[my-license kube-api-access-b32js nfs-data]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  3m56s (x2 over 6m13s)  kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[nfs-data], unattached volumes=[nfs-data my-license kube-api-access-b32js]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  100s (x2 over 8m31s)   kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[nfs-data], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-b32js nfs-data my-license]: timed out waiting for the condition
```

How to list conditions which are not met and pods are waiting for them?

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands:

```
kubectl describe pod <name>
kubectl get nodes -o wide
kubectl get volumeattachments
kubectl get componentstatus
```

You can also check your [GKE Logs](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/using-logs).